# Jupyter Lab with SSH tunnel doesn't work - how to fix?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

To launch jupyter lab on a remote server I used:

```bash
jupyter lab --no-browser --port=8889
```

And on my local machine I used:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 <my_username>@<remote_server_public_ip>
```

But when I try to connect to `localhost:8888` the it says that:
[image]

I tried to refresh and click Try Again but with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my system admin and he told me ssh to the system using `srun` is actively blocked.